# Simulating Fisher Equation (FKPP)

Tags: mathematical-modeling, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I'm researching about microbial growth (on 2D). I think that a microbial population can be modeled by the Fisher equation (any other suggestion is welcomed). My doubt is about how can I solve numerically the equation, any idea?
The equation is:
$$u_{t}-Du_{xx}=ru(1-u).$$
This is on 2D, $x=(x_{1},x_{2})$.

Comment: Are there boundary conditions?  Is the domain bounded?

Comment: The boundary should be a circle, and the boundary conditions.. I don't know, it dependes on the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

A finite-element method should work; for an implementation in two spatial dimensions, see [Numerical solution of the 1 + 2 dimensional Fisher's equation by finite elements and the Galerkin method](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895717797000150).

> A Galerkin Finite Element method in two space dimensions is presented,
>   which discretises a 1 + 2 dimensional version of this partial
>   differential equation, and thus, providing a system of ordinary
>   differential equations (ODEs) whose numerical solutions approximate
>   those of the Fisher equation. By using a particular type of form
>   functions, the off-diagonal elements of the matrix on the left-hand
>   side of the ODE system become negligibly small, which makes a
>   multiplication with the inverse of this matrix unnecessary, and
>   therefore, leads to a simpler and faster computer program with less
>   memory and storage requirements.